# cut power to a drive?

Tags: power-management

I am currently trying to turn off the power to one of my hard drives but am unable to via `hdpram`,  but I have had some success using the **gnome-disk-utility**. I am wondering what command does  gnome-disk-utility send when turning off power for hard drive ? Is there another command besides `hdpram` i could use from terminal to cut power to a drive?

**EDIT** `udisksctl power-off --block-device /dev/sdc` seems to work, however the drive does not stay powered off as it boots back up again becuase auto-mount must be enbled or the drive wont mount at all. .

if anyone knows of an alternative to `hdpram` utility I can use in Ubuntu that would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe one needs to send the drive a SCSI START STOP UNIT command to shut it down. You may have some success using the sg_start command, e.g.

```
sg_start --stop /dev/sdc
```

Comment: - This was working, but somehow isnt wokring now - could yo please have a look at this - https://askubuntu.com/questions/716725/external-3tb-usb-disc-will-not-stay-powered-off