# external 3TB USB disc will not stay powered off

Tags: hard-drive, power-management

Running Ubuntu desktop 14.04, and having problems powering down an external USB 3TB drive.

`hdparm -y /dev/disk/by-uuid/736gyh3juhg64` doesnt work because of

`G_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:` error

I did manage to find a workaround using `sudo sg_start --stop /dev/sdc` and this seemed to work for a while, but today I noticed that the drive immediately mounted & powered back up again immediately after being shut down.

I attempted to power off the drive using the **gnome-disk-utility**, and the same thing happens: the drive immediately powers back on again after being shut down. I turned off automount as well and have `nosuid,nodev,nofail,x-gvfs-show,noauto` set

I attemted to disable automounting editing `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling/automount` with **dconf editor** but this did not solve the problem

I am also not running any apps that access the drive while shutting it down.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Seagate external HDD drive and I remove my HDD from Ubuntu in two steps:

```
1. In file manager pressing the small **eject** icon.
2. Then right clicking and **safely remove** the external HDD.
```

I have not checked for others as I've only Seagate HDD so not sure whether it will work on others but you can give it a try